# getting windows userName in Mixed mode Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, cookies

I need to implement Windows authentication on top of my existing Forms Authentication web application to get the Windows user name for some of the pages in my application. For this I am following this article - [Mixed Mode Authentication](http://aspalliance.com/553_Mixed_Mode_Authentication.2) .

As mentioned in this article, I have created an additional application with 'Windows' Authentication under the same Website in IIS. I am setting 'userName' as the cookie ticket's userdata in Application_AuthenticateRequest

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      WindowsIdentity ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
      WindowsPrincipal wind_princ = new WindowsPrincipal(ident); 
      string theUserName = wind_princ.Identity.Name.ToString();   
      FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "qaAuto_winAuth_Ticket", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120), false, theUserName, "/");

       string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
       Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("myTicket", encTicket));
       Response.Redirect("http://FormsAuthenticationApp/default.aspx");  
}
```

When debugging, I can see that the cookie ticket has proper value for the user name like - myDomain/myWindowsUserName.

But after the redirect, in the 'Application_AuthenticateRequest' of FormsAuthenticationApp, when I read this cookie's value, I get NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE instead of what was set in the windows authentication myDomain/myWindowsUserName.

Have been scratching my head for past two days to figure out how to get the username in FormsAuthenticationApp. any help will be much appreciated,

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working  - yesterday when I posted the question, I had only 'Anonymous Authentication' disabled (with 'Windows Authentication' enabled ofcourse) under IIS for my Win Auth application, today I tried disabling all 'Authetications' mode except 'Windows' - i.e. Anonymous, Basic, Digest and Forms and kept only 'Windows Authentication' enabled. Also, I changed getting user from WindowsPrincipal. As I had impersonation set to true, I changed to get the username from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name . This did the trick - now I get the windows username carried over to my forms authentication site thru cookie. posting this as answer as maybe this will help someone.

thanks ppl.